# Issue when run "setup:static-content:deploy" when clone to new site

Tags: magento2

- I am copying a current site (working) to new site for demo.
- After running "composer install" and setup permission, I run: 
  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- This error is shown:

  [BadMethodCallException]
  Missing required argument $sources of Magento\Deploy\Source\SourcePool.

Anyone know what is problem? Please help. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2 first you need to compile the app so it generates core classes.
You need to run

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

before running

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Also when running setup:static-content:deploy make sure that your magento setup is in developer mode.

Answer (score 1):

Change operation mode to developer mode

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Then run below commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Hey I got the same error

I tried running

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

it given error as

```
You cannot run this command because modules are not enabled. You can enable modules by running the 'module:enable --all' command.
```

run

> php bin/magento module:enable --all
>
> sudo rm -rf var/cache/* generated/code/*
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> sudo chmod 777 -R {app,pub,generated,var}